# Grunt-injector - Handling Multiple Targets

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm new to grunt so I apologize if this question is a little silly.

I've got the following grunt file I've inherited and been modifying/updating:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  var getVersion = function(){
    var thisVer = require('./bower.json').version || '0.0.0';
    var nextVer = '';
    var nextVerList = thisVer.split('.');
    var nextPatch = new String(new Number(nextVerList.pop()) + 1);
    nextVerList.push(nextPatch);
    nextVer = nextVerList.join('.');
    return nextVer;
  }

  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: {   app:          require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
                dist:         'dist',
                quickdist:    'release-quick',
                version:      getVersion()
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        force : true,
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      }
    },
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,**/}*.html',
            'lib/**/*',
            'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
            'styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: [
            'generated/*'
          ]
        }]
      }
    },
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scss',
        cssDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/lib',
        require: [ 'bootstrap-sass', 'compass/import-once/activate' ],
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/fonts',
        relativeAssets: true
      },
      clean: {
        options: {
          clean: true,
          trace: true,
          force: true,
          debugInfo: false
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: false,
          trace: true
        }
      }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
      options: ['last 1 version'],
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/styles.css': [
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [
          {
            dest: '.tmp/scripts/scripts.js',
            src: ['app/scripts/**/*.js'],
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      all_src : {
        options : {
          mangleProperties: false,
          sourceMap : false,
        },
        files: [
          {
            dest : 'dist/scripts/scripts.min.js',
            src: [ '.tmp/scripts/**/*.js', 'app/scripts/**/*.js' ],
          },
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'app/js/',
            src: ['*.js', '!*.min.js'],
            dest: 'dist/js/',
            ext: '.min.js'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    injector: {
      options: {
        ignorePath: 'app/', // strips 'app/' from the urls of files
        "addRootSlash": false // strips leading '/' from path files
      },
      local_dependencies: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html': [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/**/*.css'],
        }
      },
      bower_dependencies: {
        options: {
          starttag: '<!-- injector:bower:{{ext}} -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html': 'bower.json'
        }
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', function (target) {
    var preTasks = [], postTasks = [];
    var baseTasks = [ 'compass:clean',  'compass:dist','autoprefixer'];

    switch(target){
      case 'dist':
          preTasks =  [ 'clean:dist'  ];
          postTasks = [ 'cssmin', 'imagemin', 'svgmin', 'ngAnnotate', 'uglify', 'copy:dist', 'injector:dist' ];
          break;
      case 'dev':
      default:
        preTasks =  [ ];
        postTasks = [ 'injector' ];

        break;
    }

    var tasks = preTasks.concat(baseTasks).concat(postTasks);
    console.log(tasks);
    return grunt.task.run(tasks);
  });


  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'build:dev'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build-dist', [
    'build:dist'
  ]);

  /*
  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'compass:clean',
    'compass:dist',
    'copy:styles',
    'imagemin',
    'svgmin',
    'injector',
    'autoprefixer',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);//*/


};
```

I'm trying to get "injector" to run on yeoman.app if the task is dev, based on the folders in the app folder, and on yeoman.dist if the task is prod, based the folders in the dist folder.

The problem I'm running into is it doesn't appear I can create a sub-item under the injector configuration one for app, one for dist, so I run it with:
injector:app
or
injector:dist

As a result the value in the config seems stuck on what it was when the config was set.

What's the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Add a var to the config, use that var in the injector code, and set that var prior to running the task list:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  var getVersion = function(){
    var thisVer = require('./bower.json').version || '0.0.0';
    var nextVer = '';
    var nextVerList = thisVer.split('.');
    var nextPatch = new String(new Number(nextVerList.pop()) + 1);
    nextVerList.push(nextPatch);
    nextVer = nextVerList.join('.');
    return nextVer;
  }
  var yeomanConfig = {    app:          require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
                          dist:         'dist',
                          quickdist:    'release-quick',
                          version:      getVersion()
                        }
  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,
    injectorTarget : yeomanConfig.app,
    clean: {
      dist: {
        force : true,
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      }
    },
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,**/}*.html',
            'lib/**/*',
            'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
            'styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: [
            'generated/*'
          ]
        }]
      }
    },
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scss',
        cssDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/lib',
        require: [ 'bootstrap-sass', 'compass/import-once/activate' ],
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/fonts',
        relativeAssets: true
      },
      clean: {
        options: {
          clean: true,
          trace: true,
          force: true,
          debugInfo: false
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: false,
          trace: true
        }
      }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
      options: ['last 1 version'],
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/styles.css': [
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [
          {
            dest: '.tmp/scripts/scripts.js',
            src: ['app/scripts/**/*.js'],
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      all_src : {
        options : {
          mangleProperties: false,
          sourceMap : false,
        },
        files: [
          {
            dest : 'dist/scripts/scripts.min.js',
            src: [ '.tmp/scripts/**/*.js', 'app/scripts/**/*.js' ],
          },
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'app/js/',
            src: ['*.js', '!*.min.js'],
            dest: 'dist/js/',
            ext: '.min.js'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    injector: {
      options: {
        ignorePath: '<%= injectorTarget %>/', // strips 'app/' from the urls of files
        "addRootSlash": false // strips leading '/' from path files
      },
      local_dependencies: {
        files: {
          '<%= injectorTarget %>/index.html': [
            '<%= injectorTarget %>/scripts/**/*.js',
            '<%= injectorTarget %>/styles/**/*.css'],
        }
      },
      bower_dependencies: {
        options: {
          starttag: '<!-- injector:bower:{{ext}} -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= injectorTarget %>/index.html': 'bower.json'
        }
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', function (target) {
    var preTasks = [], postTasks = [];
    var baseTasks = [ 'compass:clean',  'compass:dist','autoprefixer'];
    var baseTasks = [];
    switch(target){
      case 'prod':
          grunt.config.set("injectorTarget", yeomanConfig.dist);
          //preTasks =  [ 'clean:dist'  ];
          //postTasks = [ 'cssmin', 'imagemin', 'svgmin', 'ngAnnotate', 'uglify', 'copy:dist', 'injector' ];
          postTasks = [ 'injector' ];
          break;
      case 'dev':
      default:
        grunt.config.set("injectorTarget", yeomanConfig.app);
        preTasks =  [ ];
        postTasks = [ 'injector' ];

        break;
    }

    var tasks = preTasks.concat(baseTasks).concat(postTasks);
    console.log(tasks);
    return grunt.task.run(tasks);
  });


  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'build:dev'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('Serve-Prod', [
    'build:prod'
  ]);

  /*
  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'compass:clean',
    'compass:dist',
    'copy:styles',
    'imagemin',
    'svgmin',
    'injector',
    'autoprefixer',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);//*/


};
```